# Permanently enabling the scroll lock button in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

I know that one is able to enable the scroll lock button. But my question is: is there a way to permanently do this so that I do not need to enter the command in every time I start Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **xset** utility to toggle it. Either search the software center and search for **x11-xserver-utils** or enter the following from the terminal to install it.

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

All you need to do is add a new entry in settings-->session and startup with the following..

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

FYI: to turn it off..

```
xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
```

To find out how to add a something to auto-run at login see this       [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: Where do I go to access these settings? I cannot seem to find them. I tried running the command on terminal but it only enables it for the current session. Upon logging out or rebooting, I need to re-enter the command again.

Comment: This seemed to work for the ScrLK but actually messed up with other key mappings and shortcuts I had...