# How can you permanently enable scroll lock on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

This question ([Permanently enabling the scroll lock button in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544525/permanently-enabling-the-scroll-lock-button-in-ubuntu)) only provides info on how to do it manually every time.

This question ([How do I enable Scroll Lock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127167/how-do-i-enable-scroll-lock)) does not offer a permanent solution (scroll lock gets disabled again soon)

Are there any permanent solutions so I can toggle it with my buttons?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. To free the scroll lock LED if you have more than one language.

sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard
Changed XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll" to XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

Changed gsettings org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll'] to ['grp:alt_shift_toggle']

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Then
Found the permanent way
from

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164245/why-is-the-scroll-lock-key-disabled-in-cinnamon-linux-xorg?rq=1

## 2. backup your symbols file

sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us (or other Languages)

## 3. Add the following line in the xkb_symbols

"basic" { section. do not worry if that second line is not there, it is only there for some languages and was not there for us on my system.
Add this line

```
modifier_map Mod3   { Scroll_Lock };
```

before the line

include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};

YOU MAY HAVE TO DO THE SAME IN YOUR OTHER LAYOUTS IF YOU SWITCH BETWEEN LANGUAGES

## 4. Also, there is a cache where xkb layouts live. You should clear it before restarting your X server.

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/xkb/*
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.